# Debug from Visual Studio containerized standalone Angular front-end + .net backend

Tags: angular, docker, visual-studio, debugging, docker-compose

I want to debug simultaneously  backend .net project and front-end Angular project from Visual Stuidio 17.7 using docker-compose. These projects are in one solution. Please help me to fix this error: When I try to START new instance for docker-compose project with or without debugging, I got an error during building docker-compose project:

`Error  MSB3030 Could not copy the file "..\myangularfrontend.exe" because it was not found.    docker-compose  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4879`

Obviously, my standalone angular project does not contain .exe  file.

I tried to run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` for my docker-compose.yml file. And it works good - builds projects, creates and starts containers for frontend and backend.

Angular fron-end projet was added to solution from template Standalone Angular Application. Docker file in Angular project :

```go
FROM node:18.10 as node
COPY package.json /app/package.json
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN npm install

COPY . /app
EXPOSE 4200
CMD npm start
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
  myangularfrontend:
    build:
     context: ./myangularfrontend
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check"
    ports:
     - "4200:4200"

  mybackendserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mybackendserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Mybackendserver/Dockerfile
```

LaunchSettings for docker-compose project:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Docker Compose": {
      "commandName": "DockerCompose",
      "commandVersion": "1.0",
      "composeLaunchAction": "LaunchBrowser",
      "composeLaunchServiceName": "mybackendserver",
      "composeLaunchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}",
      "serviceActions": {
        "mybackendserver": "StartDebugging",
        "myangularfrontend": "StartWithoutDebugging"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

docker-compose.dcproj:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.1</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>94ec4b9d-bfa4-47ae-8d36-f7c661ce2a1e</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerLaunchAction>LaunchBrowser</DockerLaunchAction>
    <DockerServiceUrl>{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}</DockerServiceUrl>
    <DockerServiceName>mybackendserver</DockerServiceName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
    <None Include=".dockerignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the .dcproj trying "help" the Angular project. You can disable this by adding the com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name label to your Angular service.

##### Updated Docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  myangularfrontend:
    build:
     context: ./myangularfrontend
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name: ""
    command: "ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check"
    ports:
     - "4200:4200"

  mybackendserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mybackendserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Mybackendserver/Dockerfile
```

Comment: FYI: If you don't want the label in your main docker-compose.yml file you can instead put it into your docker-compose.override.yml file